# Using jasmine-jquery with Jest

Tags: jasmine, jestjs

I am trying to move from using Karma to using Jest for our testing.  We have some existing specs that are using jasmine-jquery to load html files to set up the dom for testing.

I am getting an error "Fixture could not be loaded" and I was wondering if it is possible to get Jest to serve up these files either by a configuration change or do I need to change the fixtures path (to get it to work in Karma, I had to prefix the path with 'base/').

Or is there an alternative in Jest to load fixture files?

Thanks